# if statement not working properly-PHP

Tags: php, sql

i have this problem. I have a working script, query etc and all. I can insert data and display data based on condition in if statement. if result>0, data displayed (works fine) and if result empty no data displayed(works fine also). the only problem is, i cannot make the table disappear. I just want the table disappear for God's sake. I've been having trouble for many days due to this thing. Please check if my codes are wrong. Professional help or any help is required and really appreciated at this time. thanks a million in advance.

userpage

```
<?php
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)===0){
echo "no  records";
}
else
{
echo "<tr><td></tr></td>";
echo "<table cellpadding=10 border=0 id='secondtable'>";
echo "<tr><td bgcolor=#698C00 class='white'>"."Membership"."</td>".
"<td bgcolor=#698C00 class='white'>"."Title"."</td>".
"<td bgcolor=#698C00 class='white'>"."Location"."</td>".
"<td bgcolor=#698C00 class='white'>"."Phone"."</td>".
"<td bgcolor=#698C00 class='white'>"."Picture"."</td>".
"<td bgcolor=#698C00 class='white'>"."Date Reg"."</td>".
"<td bgcolor=#698C00 class='white'>"."terminate Membership?"."</td></tr>";
while( $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
$showdateua=$row['dateua'];
$showdateua=date('d-m-Y',strtotime($showdateua));
//$showdateua=$row['dateua'];
//$showdateua=date('d.m.Y"');
//$row['dateua']=date("d.m.Y");
echo "<tr><td bgcolor=#DCDCDC>".$_SESSION['membership']=$row['membership'].
"</td><td bgcolor=#DCDCDC>".$_SESSION['title']=$row['title'].
"</td><td bgcolor=#DCDCDC>".$_SESSION['location']=$row['location'].
"</td><td bgcolor=#DCDCDC>".$_SESSION['adphone']=$row['adphone'].
"</td><td bgcolor=#DCDCDC>".
'<img src="'.$_SESSION['image1']=$row['image1'].'"alt="No image"style="width:100px;height:100px;"/>'.
"</td><td bgcolor=#DCDCDC>".$_SESSION['dateua']=$showdateua.
"</td><td bgcolor=#DCDCDC>"."<a href=\"rundelup.php?idadv=".$row['idadv']."\">".'<input type="submit" name="Delete"  value="Delete" id="Delete">'."</a></td></tr>";
/*"</td><td bgcolor=#DCDCDC>"."<a href='userpage.php?idadv=".$row['idadv']."'>"."Delete"."</a></td></tr>";*/
//echo $_SESSION['idadv']=$row['idadv'];
}
echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

include file

```
<?php
$reclimit=3;
if(isset($_GET['page'])){
$page=$_GET['page'];}
else
{
$page=1;
}
$start=(($page-1)*$reclimit);
$advert = "SELECT u.*,ua.* FROM uskkk u LEFT JOIN usddd ua ON  u.id=ua.id
WHERE u.id='".$id."'";
$result=$conn->query($advert);
$total=$result->num_rows;
$tpages=ceil($total/$reclimit);
$advert = "SELECT u.*,ua.* FROM uskkk u LEFT JOIN usddd ua ON  u.id=ua.id
WHERE u.id='".$id."'ORDER BY dateua DESC LIMIT $start,$reclimit";
$statement = $conn->prepare($advert);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->get_result(); 
?>
```

by login it should work. I tested this script below, it works fine.The table disappears when condition is met. Why is the script above not working?

```
<?php

$a="1"; 
$b="2";

if($a>0)
{
    echo "a<1";
    echo "<table border=2>";
    echo "<tr><td>gdfsdfs</td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";

}
else
{
    echo "ok";
}


?>
```

Comment: Don't think this: `$_SESSION['membership']=$row['membership']` (and the similar things) is syntactically correct. Do you have error reporting turned on for your PHP code ?

Comment: @Maximus2012 tqs pal for the reply.. oo. ok.. u mean. don't use session?..coz its repaeting itself in the while loop? yup..i turned on error reporting.. shows nothing wrong..

Comment: You can use sessions but I am not sure what you are trying to do here. You have a lot of code. I highly doubt if the error reporting is not giving you anything.

Comment: the weird thing is,everytime i login, the table is there but no data displayed. Then when i insert records via the form on the same page, then the data displays. BUt when i logout and login again , the table is there but no data. it will only trigger once i insert something via the form, secondly, the table appears all the time.

Comment: Like I said, there is too much code here and any part of it could be causing issues. You should probably try to simplify your code and narrow down to the part that might be causing the issue.

Comment: :-(...i did several times. to be honest. my previous code was quite long.. i shortened it bit by bit.. and almost everything is gone.. this is only i have left..above..

Comment: whats your opinion on the select query?..it does work but im not sure if the arrangement is correct ..i mean is it coded correctly?

Comment: Try writing the condition a different way? Try "==" instead of "===" or as a greater/less than expression? Or make them switch positions. If greater than zero, display table, else don't (instead of the reverse).

Comment: database cleared before atttempt below:

===0
nothing as usual..if wont work." and table appears"

==0
nothing as usual..if wont work." table appears"

<0..if wont work
nothing as usual.."table appears"

>0 echo "no records" table disappear..but when insert data..data and table 
will not appear.

Comment: reverse order:
===0 else triggers echos no records but.wont display data and table when inserted (table disappears)


==0
else triggers echos no records but.wont display data and table when inserted (table disappears)

<0
else triggers echos no records but.wont display data and table when inserted (table disappears)

>0
table wont dissapear...else wont trigger ..insert data no problem.

Comment: hi tqs @Langosta for your concern.. i tried the result above..whenever i managed to hide the table if condition met.. i cannot display data and the table when i insert new data..i dont know if the problem is with the if statement or the select query itself..im really banging my head on the wall now..